# Use link to CMS page that will not break when title of CMS page is changed

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block

I am struggling with the following Magento:
1. I have created a link in the content of a CMS block. Let's call this block-A.html
2. The link refers to another CMS block or page, say block-B.html
3. When changing the title of the block B into block X, the link in block A breaks.

Is there a way to avoid that link to break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CMS Page Link widget, then the link won't break when you alter the title.

Comment: @Debial Design: thanks! This is a perfect answer.